# How to install angular5 in laravel-5.6

Tags: laravel, npm, angular5, laravel-5.6, laravel-mix

I am new with laravel and angular. I want to make a laravel 5.6 project in which I use angular 5 with the help of npm. But I don't know steps to perform it. I search alot but I don't get any solution.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://laravel-angular.io/docs/1/

Comment: Or a tutorial like this? https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-to-do-app-using-angularjs-and-laravel-5-d3cfde2d7aef To give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the links that should help you:

- https://seegatesite.com/tutorial-simple-crud-angular-5-and-lumen-5-6-for-beginners/
- https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-to-do-app-using-angularjs-and-laravel-5-d3cfde2d7aef
- https://github.com/ankitparmar372/angular5.2-laravel5.6
- https://grafxflow.co.uk/blog/javascript-frameworks/create-angular-laravel-crud-app
- https://laravel-angular.io/docs/1/